# Pagenumber in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a report having 5 detail sections.

Name
ID
Phone
Country
Address

It is giving result like this.

Divya
222
9903910302
India
Pune

I kept header and corresponding details section side by side.But some times due to header length it is going to next page.
I want fit these details in one page only.
If next values came it should come in next page.
Like below

1st Page:
Abhi
54344
45365756788
India
Pune

2nd Page:

Divya
222
9903910302
India
Pune

Please suggest how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Create a group between users and try "keep group together"

Right click on Group Section on design mode. click on  Change Group. Options Tab:  Check box   'keep group together'.